# Is it legal to use freopen and after it fopen ? 

Tags: c, printf, fopen, freopen

Suppose I have a string `char* str`.
I print it to the buffer in the following way:

```
char buf[MAX_LEN];
freopen("tmp","w",stdout);
printf("%s\n",str);
fflush(stdout);
fp = fopen(tmp,"r");
if (fp == NULL) return;
fgets(buf,MAX_LEN,fp);
fclose(fp);
fclose(stdout);
```

May this code cause invalid stream buffer handle?
Is it legal to use `freopen` and after it `fopen`?
Based on constrains of my system I can't use `fprintf` and `sprintf`.

Comment: Do you actually have to pipe the `printf` output through a file to avoid `sprintf`? I would think about an own implementation of sprintf instead of fiddling with files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, it's perfectly legal and works fine. It's even its main use case, according to its man page :

> The `freopen()` function opens the file whose name is the string 
>   pointed to by path and associates the stream pointed to by stream with
>   it.  The original stream (if it exists) is closed.  The mode  argument
>   is  used just  as  in  the  `fopen()`  function.  The **primary use** of the
>   `freopen()` function is **to change the file** associated with a standard 
>   text  stream (`stderr`, `stdin`, or `stdout`)

In practice, your code won't work : there are some mistake mainly between `"tmp"` and `tmp` & missing headers. This code will work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_LEN 512

int main() {
  const char* str = "data\n";
  FILE* fp;
  char buf[MAX_LEN];

  freopen("tmp","w",stdout);
  printf("%s\n",str);
  fflush(stdout);
  fp = fopen("tmp","r");
  if (fp == NULL) return;
  fgets(buf,MAX_LEN,fp);
  // here, buf gets str's content 
  fclose(fp);
  fclose(stdout);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, while @Yakov is unlikely to run into this, there are (or at least were) systems where if you have a file open for writing, it's automatically "locked" for reading.  In that case you will generally get `NULL` back from the attempt to `fopen`-for-reading.  This is ... annoying.  I try to avoid these systems. :-)

Comment: @Coren - it is obvious about header.There was no need to duplicate my code